# LSTM with multiple input sequences and corresponding multiple output sequences

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have an issue related to reshaping input/output data for LSTM. While there are a lot of posts considering these issues, I couldn't come across to find a proper solution for this. My apologies if the mistake is quite obvious - I am rather new to the field of Deep Learning.

My issue is as follows: I performed a simulation which resulted in several sequences of time dependent data which I'd like to feed into an LSTM-network. The data (very much simplified) looks as follows:

```
X=[[[8, 0, 18, 10]
    [9, 0, 20, 7]
    [7, 0, 17, 12]]
   [[7, 0, 31, 8]
    [5, 0, 22, 9]
    [7, 0, 17, 12]]]
```

That is I have two sequences with three time steps each and 4 features per time step. Hence, the shape of X is (2,3,4). Correspondingly, what I would like to predict looks as follows

```
y=[[[10]
    [7]
   [12]]
   [[8]
    [9]
   [12]]]
```

and has shape (2,3,1). That is, the data point [8,0,18,10] is supposed to predict [10], followed by point [9,0,20,7] which should predict 7 and so on. My model then looks as follows:

```
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
```

While this seems to work without errors, my result is quite bad. Most likely, I think this is related to reshaping the output vector correctly. Also, I am not quite sure about whether or not return_sequences has to be true or not. If it is set to False, I get the error message 'Expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got an array with shape (2,3,1). Not quite sure about this. 
I was also looking into Seq2Seq modelling since I am trying to predict a sequence based on a sequence, but I couldn't find a workaround. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: Return sequences is correct, but I believe to use Dense layers after this you need to use a TimeDistributed layer (https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to resolve this for ages - using TimeDistributed massively improves the result.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. In newer keras versions, `Dense` = `TimeDistributed(Dense)`, and in older keras versions you should simply get an error.

Comment: I am using keras version 2.1.6. Probably this still counts as an older version since I don't get any errors

Comment: @DanielMöller can you clarify why this should produce an error?

Comment: On old keras versions, Dense layers only accept shape `(batch, features)`. In newer versions, it accepts any shape and does exactly the same as `TimeDistributed(Dense)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to get big numbers from a `'tanh'`, which only outputs between -1 and 1.

You can't reach 10 with `tanh`, for instance.

Either you replace the final activation with `'linear'` (outputs anything), or you normalize your output data to be within -1 and 1.

If your data is always positive, you can try using `'softplus'` instead of `'linear'`, and if you opt for normalizing data, make it between 0 and 1 and use `'sigmoid'`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The actual data of my model is indeed normalized between -1 and 1. I've just used the original data above to illustrate my problem.